# Add header to a mail using sendgrid & python

Tags: python, email, header, sendgrid

I'am trying to add a header to a mail using sendGrid:

This is the code to send an email from the official website ,

```
string apikey = "......."
sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient( apikey =apikey)
to_email = Email("....@gmail.com")   
from_email =Email ("....")
subject= '...'
content=Content('..')
mail =Mail(...)
response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail.get())
```

& it works fine,now to add a header I did (using this : https://github.com/sendgrid/smtpapi-python)

```
header = SMTPAPIHeader()
header.set_unique_args({'orderNumber':'123456'})  
mail.add_header(header)
```

then

```
response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail.get())
```

but I get :

```
in get(self)
     70             headers = {}
     71             for key in self.headers:
---> 72                 headers.update(key.get())
     73             mail["headers"] = headers
     74 

AttributeError: 'SMTPAPIHeader' object has no attribute 'get'
```

How ca, I solve this?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct function to add headers? From their examples I see they use the Personalization class. https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/blob/master/examples/helpers/mail/mail_example.py

Comment: even the personnalization, I get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yest indeed it was done with  personalization:

```
mail.personalizations[0].add_header(Header("..","..."))


response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail.get())
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this, you can use `set_headers` method to set headers for sendgrid email.

```
import sendgrid

sg = sendgrid.SendGridClient("XXXX-UR-API-KEY-XXXXX")

message = sendgrid.Mail()
message.add_to('to@email.com')
message.set_from("from@email.com>")
message.set_subject("email subject")
message.set_html('html body')

message.set_headers({'X-Priority' : '2'}) #<=== To add priority

sg.send(message)
```